# After I set the "router rip" networks, how can I check it?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, rip

In my CGR1240 I have set network `192.168.1.0` to my `router rip`, but how can I check it?

If I add more networks in rip, how can I list all the networks I have added?

I can not show the router rip in the privileged mode:

```
Router#show router rip
             ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

and in the global mode, there seems have no display command:

```
Router(config-router)#?
  auto-summary         Enter Address Family command mode
  default-information  Control distribution of default information
  distance             Define an administrative distance
  exit                 Exit from routing protocol configuration mode
  network              Enable routing on an IP network
  no                   Negate a command or set its defaults
  passive-interface    Suppress routing updates on an interface
  redistribute         Redistribute information from another routing protocol
  timers               Adjust routing timers
  version              Set routing protocol version
```

How can I list the network I have added in `router rip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are in router configuration mode, not enable mode where you run the `show` commands.

Next, you can show the configuration like @aircraft explains, but if you want to see if the networks are working, you need to get into a neighbor RIP router and do `show ip route` to see if your routes are actually working.

Answer (score 4):

You can `show running-config` to find the config:

```
Router#show running-config | begin router rip
router rip
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 12.0.0.0
```